# Does absolutely positioned elements not obey an overall div CSS command?

Tags: html, css

For instance, the example below.

Html Code:

```
<body>
        <div id="container">
            <figure id="abtex">
                <img src="images/abtex125.png" />
            </figure>   
        </div>
</body>
```

CSS code :

```
#container{
    max-width:1050px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    max-height: 1000px;
}

#abtex {
    position: absolute;
    top:-100px;
    left:400px; 
 }
```

`#abtex` would not follow the `#container` CSS commands such as the `max-width` etc right ?

Comment: Correct but you are missing: `position:relative` in your #container

Comment: no, but id you use `position:relative;` for container it'll float inside the container. PS : if top, right, bottom, left are not negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about CSS inheritance. Some CSS-properties do get inherited – most don't.

In those cases you'll need to check the specification or some CSS manual.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/max-width for your specific case. It's noted in the MDN entry, that the `max-width` property won't get inherited ("Inherited: no").

On the other hand, it's not even necessary to specify a `max-width` for the child `div#abtex`, as its maximum width will be the one f the parent element (which again can be manipulated by `overflow`).

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set a position on the `#container` element for the child's absolute position to be relative to it.

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position):

**absolute**: Do not leave space for the element.  Instead, **position it at a specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor or to the containing block**. Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins, they do not collapse with any other margins.

In other words, since `#container` doesn't have a position set, the closest positioned ancestor = the body. Setting `position:relative` on `#container` is the typical solution for this.